# What is the purpose of the EXM MessageStatistics admin page?

Tags: exm

I have heard about and seen referenced the page `/sitecore/admin/MessageStatistics.aspx` which looks like is for EXM statistics. What exactly is the purpose of this page, when should I use it, and what functions does it perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.0.2, in the content tree, under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/Instance Tasks/Content Management Primary` there are scheduled tasks related to the message statistics.
[image]

By default, they are scheduled to run at gap of 1 minute for today, 1 hour for recent and 24 hours for older or missing.

The page you have mentioned is another interface to trigger the same on-demand and even for a particular message.